# Plug-In Error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, header, manifest

I use a plug-in directly from an existing JAR. When the project is created there is an error in the **MANIFEST.MF** file and also in my  **Referenced Libraries** subfolder, which is named after the **Plug-in ID**. But just on that folder, the (default package) is okay.

The error says:

```
Invalid manifest header Export-Package: ";version="1.0.0""
```

And the location of the error is Line 1, which is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0.0
```

And no matter how I modify it, it stays as an error.

Update:

Here's the full MANIFEST:MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: ExcorpPlugin
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.Excorp.PS.ExcorpPlugin
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-ClassPath: .
Bundle-Vendor: EXCORP
Export-Package: ;version="1.0.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
```

Comment: Show us the full MANIFEST.MF

Comment: There it is, my MANIFEST.MF file, as shown in the text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manifest.mf line

```
Export-Package: ;version="1.0.0"
```

is wrong, it should contain a package name such as:

```
Export-Package: package.name;version="1.0.0"
```

Deleting the line from the manifest will fix the error, but you need to research if the plugin should be exporting one or more packages.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, just one question. I have only one package, the default package, so in Export-Package, it would be package.default;version="1.0.0" ??

Comment: You only use Export-Package if you want other plugins to be able to see the code in the package. Using the default package for an Eclipse plugin is not a good idea, I don't think it will work with export package at all, use a proper package.